# Activerecord query not returning all results

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've been having a problem with an ActiveRecord query in Rails 4:

**my models:**

```
class Addressee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :emails
end

class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, foreign_key: :from_id, class_name: "Addressee"
  has_and_belongs_to_many :addressees
end
```

**my schema.rb**

```
  create_table "addressees", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "token",      limit: nil
    t.string   "domain",     limit: nil
    t.string   "email",      limit: nil
    t.string   "name",       limit: nil
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "addressees_emails", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "addressee_id"
    t.integer  "email_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

    create_table "emails", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "message_id", limit: nil
    t.integer  "from_id"
    t.string   "subject",    limit: nil
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "date"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

**my query:**

```
# Returns correct emails
query_params = { "addressees.email" => "test@example.com"  }
@emails = Email.includes(:addressees).where(query_params).references(:addressees)
```

**my problem:**

```
# Returns only the addressee matching the email from query params
@emails.last.addressees
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Addressee id: 12, token: "test", domain: "example.com", email: "test@example.com", name: nil, created_at: "2014-09-25 14:06:34", updated_at: "2014-09-25 14:06:34">]>

#Returns the wrong count
@emails.last.addressees.size
#=> 1

#Returns the correct count (because it does a new query)
@emails.last.addressees.count
#=> 3
```

**my question:**

How can I modify the query to include all addressees without the need to do another query?. I'm passing the @emails var to my json serializer and now it only includes 1 addressee instead of all 3.

Comment: The query is limiting the addresses to the emails that you specified using a LEFT OUTER JOIN.  You will have to reload the association to get past this, which requires a new query.  This is a limitation of ActiveRecord.  What DBMS are you using?  You will need to write the SQL yourself.

Comment: ```@emails = Email.where('emails.id IN SELECT(email_id FROM addressees_emails WHERE addressee_id IN (SELECT id FROM addressees WHERE email IN (?)))', %w[test@example.com test2@example.com]).includes(:addressees)```

I'm unable to test the query at this moment, but if you are familiar with SQL, you should see where I was going with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@emails = Email.where('emails.id IN SELECT(email_id FROM addressees_emails WHERE addressee_id IN (SELECT id FROM addressees WHERE email IN (?)))', %w[test@example.com test2@example.com]).includes(:addressees)
```

Comment: An explanation would help.